# Mongoos lookup not return the desired results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have to collections,User and Patient.One user can have multiple number of patients.I am writing a function that will send the user details alongwith the patient details associated with it.I am using mongoose lookup for that.But, i am not getting the same results.

```
const User = require('../models/User-model/user');
const Patient = require('../models/patient/patient');
```

Patient schema

```
_id:ObjectID("5f469bd60ca1a76de048ef47")
patientIllness:Array
userID:"5f3ac77ae5fd03695c7f34e7"
firstName:"rahul"
lastName:"sharma"
photo:"https://picsum.photos/200/300"
age:51
gender:"male"
addressLine1:"Jamuna Paar"
adressLine2:"East Delhi"
city:"New Delhi"
pinCode:"500078"
__v:0
```

User Schema

```
_id:ObjectId("5f3ac77ae5fd03695c7f34e7")
active:"active"
email:"adishrtv10@gmail.com"
phone:"7748973500"
__v:0
```

Function

```
 patientDetails: async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('User information will be provided');
    const {id} = req.user;

    User.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: {id: id},
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'Patient',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'userID',
                    as: 'patient_details',
                },
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$patient_details',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
                },
            },
        ],
        (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.send('Error');
            }
            res.send(result);
        }
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User collection's `_id` type is Object Id and patient collection's `userID` is string, you need to convert one of the field type, and it require to use [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup),

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "patient",
      as: "patient_details",
      let: { id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                { $toObjectId: "$userID" }, // this will convert string to object id
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O0Xp4tX8ZVi)

Comment: I am getting an input id from frontend as string. I am using it to find the user and then lookup for the patients assosciated with it.I think,there is a problem while using isMatch as we are still comparing and objectid with a string.How can i address that?

Comment: use `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` to convert string to object id and then try.

Comment: This is working but i am not able to see the patient details alongwith user details. I am only seeing user details.I am doing it like this.   const result = await User.aggregate([
            {
               the code
        ]);
        res.send(result);

Comment: check type of `userID` field in `patient` collection its object or string? and check collection name  that i have predicted `patient` in my answer but you can correct it as per your DB. might be its is capital in your query and i have used in small

Comment: Actually, i changed the userID to ObjectId type and changed your code in the following way                        pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ['$userID', '$$id'],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],                    the names of collection was corrected

Comment: add your data and debug it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/_0IcB9zR8gh , or send me after adding data if its not work.

Comment: I have written exact same code in nodejs.It is working in mongodb playground but not in my node application.Maybe there is an issue while responding the result.

Comment: okay you can ask new question with your code , you will get solution.